# Can't load/save JPG image in Qt

Tags: qt, jpeg, qimage, qpixmap

I can't load/save `jpg` image in Qt. I checked the `imageformat` folder in plugins folder and I found the `dll/lib` files related to this extension.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void loadImages(){

    QImage image;
    QString folderName = "C:\\img-src\\";
    bool isLoaded;
    for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
        QString fileName = folderName + QString::number(i) + ".jpg";
        isLoaded = image.load(fileName,"JPG");
        if(isLoaded){
            qDebug() << "loaded";
        }else{
            qDebug() << "not loaded";
        }

        //Rest of the code

        }



}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Are you saving a QImage? QPixmap? More info is definitely needed

Comment: @StuartBuckingham yes, I'm saving it as a QImage.

Comment: execute `qDebug() << QFileInfo(fileName).exists();`

Comment: code works for me.
Does you program have the permissions to read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was.
I have to copy the `imageformats` folder next to the exe file of the program to enable loading/saving jpg files.